# Where does this `#` in my array output come from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

EDIT I simplified

```
out.push('<li>' + clicks[i].target + outputTime + 'm</li>');
        }
(".taskList ul li p").html(out.join(''));
```

to

```
$(".taskList ul li p").html(outputTime);
```

/EDIT
 I am using the jQuery Jeditable plugin with callback function to start a timer when a field is changed.

When a button is clicked the time between the Jedit and click event is calculated and the value is placed in the dom next to the edited '..click to edit' text- before this whole Div is moved to a new section, the timer is reset and a new Jeditable instance is created in place of the original.

My difficulty is that that I took much of the timer portion of my code from a jsfiddle I found on another stack overflow post http://jsfiddle.net/wwnyY/11/ . The output from this is placing a # character infront of my result.

I figured out that the timer code is useing the push() method and this is returning an array and I guess this is where my extra character is coming from. Arrays are my current stumbling block as far as programming is concerned and I wondered if anyone could explain either how I could properly process the array to remove the # or else what i could replace it with in the code below (i couldnt put up an external link in a  jsfiddle so have posted the code http://binarygeometry.net/test/index.html )

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="eight columns">
   <div class="row taskList">
       <ul>
           <li>
          <div class="nine columns task">
          <div class="edit">
                        ..click to edit
                      </div>
          </div>
              <div class="three columns time">
                     <p>00.00</p>
              </div>
       </li>
       </ul>
 </div>
     <ul class="row doneList">
     <li>

     </li>
 </ul>       
</div>

<div class="four columns">
<p><a href="#" class="success button" id="done">Go!</a></p>
</div>
</div>






 $(document).ready(function() {

 $(".edit").editable("echo.php", {
     placeholder : "Click me to edit",
     loadtype : "POST",
     callback: function(value, settings) {
      startTime = new Date().getTime();
      console.log(startTime);
     }
 });


$("#done").click(function(e){

    function update_output() {  

        var out  = [],
            displayTime;

        for (var i = 0, len = clicks.length; i < len; i++) {
            displayTime = (clicks[i].time - startTime);
            console.log(displayTime);
            outputTime = displayTime //* 0.00001666666;
            console.log(outputTime);
            outputTime = outputTime.toFixed(0);
            console.log(outputTime);
            out.push('<li>' + clicks[i].target + outputTime + 'm</li>');
        }
        $(".taskList ul li p").html(out.join(''));
    }

    var clicks = [];

    clicks.push({ time : new Date().getTime(), target : $(this).attr('href') });
    update_output();


    $(".taskList ul li").appendTo(".doneList")
    $(".edit").removeClass("edit").unbind("click.editable");
    $("<li><div class='nine columns task'><div class='edit'>..click to edit</div><div class='three columns time'><p></p></div></li>")
        .appendTo(".taskList ul");

    $(".edit").editable("echo.php", {
         placeholder : "Click me to edit",
         loadtype : "POST",
         callback: function(value, settings) {
            startTime = new Date().getTime();
            console.log(startTime);
         }
     });
    e.preventDefault();//
});


 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't you want adding `#` in URL? Then add `return false;` in bottom of your `click` handler. (use instead of `e.preventDefault()`)

Comment: Thanks matt, I don't think that was it though. It is the `#98098` which is returned by `out.push('<li>' + clicks[i].target + outputTime + 'm</li>');` once the code is run that I am having difficulty with

Comment: that did solve the file.html# problem that I didn't know I had though. thanks!

Comment: @happilyUnStuck, please mark the answer as accepted instead of changing the title to `SOLVED`. Click the checkmark to the left of this answer.

Comment: Hi macek, it wasn't the answer though. It was helpful (which I +1 for) out of context, but didn't really address my question at all. I have added the code fixes I made to the top of my post, but feel it would be misleading to mark this answer as correct. Are you able to advise if there is a better way for me to mark my question as answered?

Comment: @macek Just answered my own question again. doh!, it's the big button that says Answer This Question at the bottom of the page. Didn't realise that worked for my own question :D

Answer (score 0):

By simplifying

```
 out.push('<li>' + clicks[i].target + outputTime + 'm</li>');
    }
 (".taskList ul li p").html(out.join(''));
```

to

```
//out.push('<li>' + clicks[i].target + outputTime + 'm</li>');
  }
$(".taskList ul li p").html(outputTime);
```

the html() function no longer outputs the variable through the push() method but simply inserts the outputTime variable as a node.

Comment: I have to wait for two days. Maybe in this time I might get a better answer than my hacky fix ;)